# pyrogram [Errno 111] Connection refused on pythonanywhere.com

Tags: python, telegram-bot, pythonanywhere, pyrogram

I write a test bot for telegram by [Pyrogram](https://docs.pyrogram.org/) library. It work on my local but on [pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) bash not work and can not connect:

```
INFO:pyrogram.crypto.aes:Using TgCrypto
Pyrogram v1.2.9, Copyright (C) 2017-2021 Dan <https://github.com/delivrance>
Licensed under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License v3 or later (LGPLv3+)

INFO:pyrogram.connection.connection:Connecting...
WARNING:pyrogram.connection.connection:Unable to connect due to network issues: [Errno 111] Connection refused
INFO:pyrogram.connection.connection:Connecting...
WARNING:pyrogram.connection.connection:Unable to connect due to network issues: [Errno 111] Connection refused
INFO:pyrogram.connection.connection:Connecting...
WARNING:pyrogram.connection.connection:Unable to connect due to network issues: [Errno 111] Connection refused
WARNING:pyrogram.connection.connection:Connection failed! Trying again...
INFO:pyrogram.connection.connection:Disconnected
INFO:pyrogram.session.session:Session stopped
INFO:pyrogram.connection.connection:Connecting...
WARNING:pyrogram.connection.connection:Unable to connect due to network issues: [Errno 111] Connection refused
INFO:pyrogram.connection.connection:Connecting...
WARNING:pyrogram.connection.connection:Unable to connect due to network issues: [Errno 111] Connection refused
INFO:pyrogram.connection.connection:Connecting...
WARNING:pyrogram.connection.connection:Unable to connect due to network issues: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Then when I press ctrl+c to stop app:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/taregh/bot.py", line 37, in <module>
    client.run()
  File "/home/taregh/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/utilities/run.py", line 61, in run
    self.start()
  File "/home/taregh/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrogram/sync.py", line 56, in async_to_sync_wrap
    return loop.run_until_complete(coroutine)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 629, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 596, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1890, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "/home/taregh/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/utilities/start.py", line 53, in start
    is_authorized = await self.connect()
  File "/home/taregh/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/auth/connect.py", line 46, in connect
    await self.session.start()
  File "/home/taregh/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrogram/session/session.py", line 127, in start
    await self.connection.connect()
  File "/home/taregh/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrogram/connection/connection.py", line 57, in connect
    await self.protocol.connect(self.address)
  File "/home/taregh/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrogram/connection/transport/tcp/tcp_abridged_o.py", line 40, in connect
    await super().connect(address)
  File "/home/taregh/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrogram/connection/transport/tcp/tcp.py", line 82, in connect
    self.socket.connect(address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/socks.py", line 47, in wrapper
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/socks.py", line 780, in connect
    super(socksocket, self).connect((dest_addr, dest_port))
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I installed all requirements. But dose not work at all.

Comment: If you're using a free account, you have restricted internet access to whitelisted domains -- if the endpoint your script is hitting is not whitelisted on PA, you will not be able to connect.  If it is whitelisted, you probably need to configure proxy, see: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/403ForbiddenError/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `Unable to connect due to network issues: [Errno 111] Connection refused`

Error should be quite clear. The connection is being refused.

Pythonanywhere doesn't let you use random ports and does not work with Telegram. Libraries that work via HTTP (Python-Telegram-Bot for example) should work, but Pyrogram does not.